# Jquery SlideToggle needs to be clicked 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using slideToggle to show some data in a div. Here's my code:

```
$('a.more').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();            
            var id = $(this).attr('cid');
            $.post('<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/teacher/class-members');?>',
            {cid: id},
            function(data) {                              
                $("div[cid='" + id + "']").slideToggle(500, function(){
                    $(this).html(data);
                });
            })
        });
```

The problem is that I need to click 2 times for the slide to activate and show the data. Why is this happening? It only needs to do this one time per link. So when I'm first viewing a page and I click on a link with class "more" I need to click 2 times (the $.post is executed 2 times :-/ ) for the toggle to work. After that It will work as it should, 1 click toggle down, 1 click toggle up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the initial css state of `div[cid=`, if it is set to display block it will hide the div and than assign the html in the callback.

If you set the div to `display:none` it should work the first time however it will be jumpy as it only will set the html on the callback of `slideToggle`.

If you want to slide up on each click and load the data try this out:

```
$('a.more').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('cid');
    var $div = $("div[cid='" + id + "']").slideUp(function(){$(this).empty();});
    $.post('<?php echo $this->baseUrl(' / teacher / class - members ');?>', {
        cid: id
    }, function (data) {
        $div.html(data).slideDown(500);
    })
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/eRg3y/1/).

Comment: the div is empty, has no state attached to it....hmmm maybe that's why. I should set a display: none probably right? which is the best way to make this work?

Comment: if it has no content it still is consider visible and will be set to display:none via the first call to `slideToggle`

Comment: right, thanks. i set the property: display:none. It is a little jumpy, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: See my update, since you are loading data dynamically it might be good to split the slide toggles separately.  slideUp on click, once the data is appended slideDown.

Comment: not working as i was expecting it to work:)) now it slides up and down in 1 click. I'll stick with the jumpy feeling of toggle :) or just do a hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.more').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();            
            var id = $(this).attr('cid');
            $.post('<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/teacher/class-members');?>',
            {cid: id},
            function(data) {                              
                $("div[cid='" + id + "']").html(data).slideToggle(500);
            })
        });
```

Works nicely like this, no jumpy feeling.